# Java Time zone transition period from EDT to EST

Tags: java, timezone, dst

Problem statement: Convert "2014-11-02 01:00:15 EST" to GMT.

This seems easy enough. But why is the below code giving the wrong answer?

Background:

- EDT aka GMT-4
- EST aka GMT-5
- 2014-11-02 01:00:15 EST == 2014-11-02 06:00:15 GMT
- If I user the commented out date string it works!!!
- EDT(until Nov 2, 2014 at 2am) -> at 2am we go to 1am EST

Code Example:

```
ZoneId gmt = ZoneId.of("GMT");
//String from = "2014-11-02 01:00:15 GMT-05:00";
String from = "2014-11-02 01:00:15 EST";

final DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatterone = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
ZnedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(from, dateTimeFormatterone);
ZonedDateTime gmtzonedDateTime = zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(gmt);
String result = gmtzonedDateTime.format(dateTimeFormatterone);
```

This is what the outcome is.

```
result == "2014-11-02 05:00:15 GMT"
```

Shouldn't it be
    result == "2014-11-02 06:00:15 GMT"

Any help would be great. I am thinking this is a bug in Java. But I am also think I am making a error somewhere.

Thanks
Paul

Comment: I believe you have it backwards.  EDT is GMT-4, and EST is GMT-5.  Which means the output (05:00:15 GMT) was correct.

Comment: You are right. I updated the example. If you have a chance could you look at my updated example.

Comment: This is tricky, and perhaps heuristic, because one can always specify a time as EST even while EDT is active.  Which means 01:00:15 (and the entire hour from 1 to 2 AM) occurs twice, consecutively, in EST on that night.  So when Java parses that date, should the parser assume the first occurrence of that hour, or the second occurrence?

Answer (score 0):

The given GMT abbreviation of the offset is without `:`. Change

```
String from = "2014-11-02 01:00:15 GMT-05:00";
```

to

```
String from = "2014-11-02 01:00:15 GMT-0500";
```

And some logical error:

If you go from 2 to 1 at Nov 2, 2014 at 2am, isn't it correct to go from 6 to 5 as well and 5 am is correct?

Comment: This thing is this "2014-11-02 01:00:15 GMT-05:00" returns the correct GMT value of "2014-11-02 06:00:15 GMT". This "2014-11-02 01:00:15 EST" returns "2014-11-02 05:00:15 GMT". Not sure why this is happening because this "2014-11-02 01:00:15 GMT-05:00" and this "2014-11-02 01:00:15 EST" should be equal. Now if you put in "2014-11-02 02:00:00 GMT-05:00" or "2014-11-02 02:00:00 EST" you get the correct result of "2014-11-02 07:00:00 GMT". It is just in that windows where you move from 2am EDT to 1am EST where I am seeing this issue

Comment: Yes, but let's assume we don't have DST. Then "2014-11-02 06:00:15" GMT would be right. Now, on Nov 2, 1am, we put the clock 1 hour back and we get one hour less for all hours past this time. Thus: "2014-11-02 05:00:15 GMT"